# Drag-Drop to/from listview multiple items at once?

Tags: vba, vb6

I'm using the following events for dragging one item from a listview to another one, and it works perfectly. **I there a way to drag more than one item at once?**

```
 Private Sub ListView1_OLEDragDrop(Index As Integer, Data As MSComctlLib.DataObject, Effect As Long, Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, y As Single)
    Dim n As Long, li As ListItem
    DropTargetIndex = Index
    If Index = 1 And ListView1(1).ListItems.Count > 0 Then Exit Sub
    Set li = ListView1(DragSource).SelectedItem
    ListView1(DragSource).ListItems.Remove li.Index
    If ListView1(Index).DropHighlight Is Nothing Then
        n = ListView1(Index).ListItems.Count + 1
    Else
        n = ListView1(Index).DropHighlight.Index
    End If
    With ListView1(Index).ListItems.Add(n, li.Key, li.Text, li.Icon, li.SmallIcon)
        For n = 1 To li.ListSubItems.Count
            .ListSubItems.Add , li.ListSubItems(n).Key, li.ListSubItems(n).Text
        Next
        .Selected = True
    End With
    Set ListView1(Index).DropHighlight = Nothing
End Sub
Private Sub ListView1_OLEDragOver(Index As Integer, Data As MSComctlLib.DataObject, Effect As Long, Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, y As Single, State As Integer)
    If Index = 0 And ListView1(1).ListItems.Count > 0 Then Exit Sub
    '    If DropTargetIndex = 3 And ListView1(DragSource).SelectedItem.ListSubItems(3) > 5 Then Exit Sub
    Set ListView1(Index).DropHighlight = ListView1(Index).HitTest(X, y)
End Sub
Private Sub ListView1_OLEStartDrag(Index As Integer, Data As MSComctlLib.DataObject, AllowedEffects As Long)
    If Index = 0 And ListView1(1).ListItems.Count > 0 Then Exit Sub
    '    If DropTargetIndex = 3 And ListView1(DragSource).SelectedItem.ListSubItems(3) > 5 Then Exit Sub
    DragSource = Index
    AllowedEffects = vbDropEffectMove
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have working code, my goal was to modify your code with the needed changes.

The first step would be to set the MultiSelect property for each ListView to True.

The second step would be to add a loop inside the DragDrop event.  Here's the modified code:

```
Private Sub ListView1_OLEDragDrop(Index As Integer, Data As MSComctlLib.DataObject, Effect As Long, Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, y As Single)
   Dim n As Long, li As ListItem, i As Long
   DropTargetIndex = Index
   If Index = 1 And ListView1(1).ListItems.Count > 0 Then Exit Sub
    
   For i = ListView1(DragSource).ListItems.Count To 1 Step -1
      If ListView1(DragSource).ListItems(i).Selected Then
         Set li = ListView1(DragSource).ListItems(i)
         ListView1(DragSource).ListItems.Remove li.Index
         If ListView1(Index).DropHighlight Is Nothing Then
             n = ListView1(Index).ListItems.Count + 1
         Else
             n = ListView1(Index).DropHighlight.Index
         End If
         With ListView1(Index).ListItems.Add(n, li.Key, li.Text, li.Icon, li.SmallIcon)
             For n = 1 To li.ListSubItems.Count
                 .ListSubItems.Add , li.ListSubItems(n).Key, li.ListSubItems(n).Text
             Next
             .Selected = True
         End With
      End If
   Next
    
   Set ListView1(Index).DropHighlight = Nothing
End Sub
```